# CSS-filter: Invert does not work in mozilla

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-filters

Title describes the problem.
Here is my code

```
.img { 
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

Works fine fine in chrome, but firefox does not display inverted colors.

**EDIT**
Browser versions: Firefox 29.0.1 && Chrome  36.0.1985.125

Comment: What versions of these browsers are you using? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Jerodev that question is from almost a year ago, it could've changed in the meantime. However, according to this site, `filter` is only partially supported and I guess invert isn't one of them yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: Im using the newest versions of both browsers @BennoZeeman
Firefox 29.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has partial support from 30th version, according to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

And according to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility):

> The functional values of filter are **disabled by default** and controlled by the `layout.css.filters.enabled` pref.

---

> Before Firefox 34, Gecko only implements the url() form of the filter property; as chaining was not implemented then, only one url() was allowed (or when the layout.css.filters.enabled pref is set to false).

#### Update:

In your post edit you mentioned that the firefox version is 29. Then it definitely doesn't support Filter CSS property as I explained above.